# Show the output before the exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a function (2 IN parameters) that returns the average of salaries that a person has had, and if the person doesn't exist in the database (id and name aren't present in the DB) I will raise an exception or if he hasn't any salary then another exception will be raised.

The thing is that I have a collection with some id & names that will generate different outputs for different parameters,
half of them will generate the normal output meaning that the people are in the DB and have salary and the other half don't have a salary or don't exist in the DB.

SQL Developer will show the user defined exception even though I put the "correct" people before the "incorrect" people.

What can I do to print the returned message before the exception is raised?

Comment: Show us the function please.

Comment: @VBoka the function works as it should. The problem is: if I call the function 3 times in a block with parameters that are in the DB, it will produce 3 different outputs but if I call it with parameters that aren't in the DB, it will just print the exception ignoring the 3 outputs from before.

Comment: show us the function please. You say "the function works as it should" but then you describe what is not working...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're doing that. People *usually* do it in a (cursor) loop. If you're doing the same, then you'll need to include additional `begin-exception-end` block within the loop itself.

I don't know your tables so this is kind of a stupid code, but should give you an idea:

```
declare
  l_ename emp.ename%type;
  l_sal   emp.sal%type;
begin
  for cur_d in (select deptno, dname from dept) loop
    begin                                         --> begins here
      select e.ename, e.sal 
        into l_ename, l_sal
        from emp e
        where e.deptno = cur_d.deptno;

    exception                                     --> handle errors
      when no_data_found then
        null;
      when too_many_rows then
        null;
    end;                                          --> ends here
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: This looks nice, but I have another question. My function already treats the possible exceptions and I just have to call it inside the block. Can I treat the function exceptions in the block? By that, I mean moving the exceptions handling from the function to the block?

Comment: You can handle any exception you want, but - this code (I posted) will handle errors you get within the loop. If you move those handlers out, you'll be where you're now - in unhandled errors.